# C# Next/Previous Button Logic

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I have a Windows form app. I get data based on a row position in a DataTable. I have a TotalCount variable and a CurrentPos variable. The button next should get the next row and the button previous should get the previous. These buttons should be enabled/disabled when there is data available.

My brain is much can you provide the logic

Comment: My brain is much too.  How is babby formed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it not a simple

```
m_NextButton.Enabled =  CurrentPos < (TotalCount - 1) ;
m_PreviousButton.Enabled = CurrentPos > 0;
```

You need to call this when you

1. Add to your DataTable
2. Change Your Selection
3. Remove from your datatable

Comment: At what point do you increment the CurrentPos, before the call to get records or after. When the form starts the CurrentPost = 0 but you can't increment before the call to get records as it will miss the first record

Comment: Not to worry, I have done it. Thanks for your help, having a bad brain day!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at the [BindingNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.aspx) class which will do this for you